# Product image by ftp url

Tags: magento2, product, api, product-images, url

I need to pass an url of an ftp to be the product image by the magento api, can I do this?
Something like

```
{
            "attribute_code": "image",
            "value": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5c/Alan-Walker-_Faded.jpg"
        }
```

I found the api to pass the image but it asks for a file and a base64 as below but this way it doesn't answer me.

```
{
"entry": {
"media_type": "image",
"label": "new_picture",
"types": [
  "image"
],
"file": "pic1.jpg",
"content": {
  "base64_encoded_data": "",
  "type": "image",
  "name": "pic1.jpg"
}
  }
}
```

Comment: You mean you want to pass product image url in rest api?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that's exactly what I need

Comment: Is it useful for you?

Answer (score 1):

You need to start emulation using this below code :

```
$this->appEmulation->startEnvironmentEmulation($storeId, \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, true);
```

After that, you can get product image full url in your rest api.

For more details : **[Click Here](https://www.rohanhapani.com/magento-2-get-product-image-url-in-rest-api/)**

Hope, It will helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: **no**

You'll need to send the base64 encoded image in the `base64_encoded_data` param

Comment: So do I necessarily need to save the image in the magento files and the bank? it doesn't seem to make sense ...

Comment: That is the default way, another way is to have a cdn or another public image repository (not ftp), if that is the case, please tell me as I might have a solution.